# How do we iteratively accept input from single input form through looping with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

I had the following code and I wondered if the question I asked is implementable:

```js
var sum = 0;
while (document.getElementById("number").value != 0) { //while the user keeps on entering >0, add to sum
  sum = sum + document.getElementById("number").value;
}
document.getElementById("resultpara").value = sum;
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="number">Enter a number:</label>
  <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
  <label for="number">Result:</label>
  <label for="resultpara"></label>
  <p id="resultpara"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You will need an input event listener. Also, on form submit, the page will refresh (wiping any variable values to their defaults) unless you stop the propagation of submit event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an input event listener. Also, on form submit, the page will refresh (wiping any variable values to their defaults) unless you stop the propagation of submit event

```js
var sum=0;
document.getElementById("number").addEventListener("input", function(event) {
  var number = Number(event.target.value) || 0;
  if (event.target.value !== 0) {
    sum += number;
  }
  document.getElementById("resultpara").textContent = sum;
  event.target.value = null;
});
```

```html
<form>
            <label for="number">Enter a number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" id="number">
            <label for="number">Result:</label>            
            <label for="resultpara"></label>
            <p id="resultpara"></p>
            
        </form>
```

Comment: Ohhh, now I see how it goes. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: How would the user enter a value greater than 9?

Comment: Good point, in that case instead of input event, change would be more suitable.